# Transforming observations into variables

Tags: r

I have a data of the format:

```
|id|genre1|genre2 |genre3 |
|1 |action|comedy |romance|
|2 |comedy|romance|       |
|3 |romance|      |       |
```

I want to convert my data to be of the format:

```
|id|action|comedy|romance|
|1 |1     |1     |1      |
|2 |0     |1     |1      |
|3 |0     |0     |1      |
```

What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the empty elements are empty character strings (i.e. they contain no spaces), you can first replace those elements with `NA` and then use the *reshape2* package to reshape the data.

```
is.na(df) <- df == ""

library(reshape2)
dcast(melt(df, 1, na.rm = TRUE), id ~ value, length)
#   id action comedy romance
# 1  1      1      1       1
# 2  2      0      1       1
# 3  3      0      0       1
```

Or a one-liner for fun, leaving the original data unchanged.

```
dcast(melt(replace(df, df == "", NA), 1, na.rm = TRUE), id ~ value, length)
#   id action comedy romance
# 1  1      1      1       1
# 2  2      0      1       1
# 3  3      0      0       1
```

**Original Data Used:**

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:3, genre1 = c("action", "comedy", "romance"
), genre2 = c("comedy", "romance", ""), genre3 = c("romance", 
"", "")), .Names = c("id", "genre1", "genre2", "genre3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reshaping.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  gather(number, genre, genre1:genre3) %>%
  filter(genre != "") %>%
  select(-number) %>%
  mutate(one = 1) %>%
  spread(genre, one, fill = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

With base R, you can use `reshape` and `table`:

```
mydf <-data.frame(id=1:3,
genre1=c("action","comedy","romance"),
genre2=c("comedy","romance",NA),
genre3=c("romance",NA,NA))

colnames(mydf)[2:4] <- paste0("genre.",colnames(mydf)[2:4])
m_data <- reshape(mydf,direction="long", varying=2:4)
with(m_data, table(id, genre))

   genre
id  action comedy romance
  1      1      1       1
  2      0      1       1
  3      0      0       1
```